# EF Code First Migration doesn't compile

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF Code First to generate my DB Schema (EF 6, .NET 4.5.2). I have two classes I want to insert:

```
public class MatrixFile
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public virtual List<MatrixData> Data { get; set; }
}

public class MatrixData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OdPairKey { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my DbContext

```
public class MyDataContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<MatrixFile> MatrixFiles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MatrixData> MatrixData { get; set; }
}
```

I try and generate my DB Schema in EF by typing the following commands into the package manager console:

```
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration GenerateDatabase
```

This is the migration that EF has generated for me:

```
public partial class GenerateDatabase : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.MatrixDatas",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    OdPairKey = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Value = c.Double(nullable: false),
                    MatrixFile_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.MatrixFiles", t => t.MatrixFile_Id)
            .Index(t => t.MatrixFile_Id, name: ""IX_MatrixData_MatrixFile_Id"");

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.MatrixFiles",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    FilePath = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.MatrixDatas", "MatrixFile_Id", "dbo.MatrixFiles");
        DropIndex("dbo.MatrixDatas", ""IX_MatrixData_MatrixFile_Id"");
        DropTable("dbo.MatrixFiles");
        DropTable("dbo.MatrixDatas");
    }
}
```

The line `.Index(t => t.MatrixFile_Id, name: ""IX_MatrixData_MatrixFile_Id"");` has a compile error because of the double quotes around `IX_MatrixData_MatrixFile_Id`. Why is this happening? How can I get it to generate the correct migration code without manually hacking the migration?

Comment: why in earth there is a dobule quote there? just remove it and it will work

Comment: Hi @Stormhashe. Your comment is basically rephrasing my question, but with much worse spelling and grammar. I know I can just fix it by removing the superfluous quotes. However, do you know why EF is generating the code?

Comment: Are you using MSSQL?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon yes and no. I am using the default LocalDB connection which uses the `System.Data.SqlClient` provider.

Comment: I have just trawled through the EF6 code. It looks like you are manually setting the name of the Index somewhere .. Can you post your `OnModelCreating` override or anywhere else you are setting the Index name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further explain my comment on the OP, EF has this in the Migrations Scaffolder ...

```
// System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator
/// <summary>
/// Quotes an identifier using appropriate escaping to allow it to be stored in a string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="identifier"> The identifier to be quoted. </param>
/// <returns> The quoted identifier. </returns>
protected virtual string Quote(string identifier)
{
    return "\"" + identifier + "\"";
}
```

...which is called by the table scaffolder and the index scaffolder. This generates the code as a string to be written to the .cs file...

```
// System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator
private void WriteIndexParameters(CreateIndexOperation createIndexOperation, IndentedTextWriter writer)
{
    if (createIndexOperation.IsUnique)
    {
        writer.Write(", unique: true");
    }
    if (createIndexOperation.IsClustered)
    {
        writer.Write(", clustered: true");
    }
    if (!createIndexOperation.HasDefaultName)
    {
        writer.Write(", name: ");
        writer.Write(this.Quote(createIndexOperation.Name));
    }
}
```

The issue is that if the `idenitifier` is `"\"IX_MYIndex\""` you are going to get the quotes **unescaped** in the code. What you really need - if you need quotes for any reason is `"\\\"IX_MYIndex\\\""` so that the escape sequence is valid in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You were right on the money @MichaelCoxon. My intention was to use this with SQLite eventually and I had the `SQLite.CodeFirst` package installed so I can use it to initialise the database. I had the following code in the DataContext:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EngineDataContext>(modelBuilder);
        Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);
    }
```

Which seemed to generate the rogue code. Removing it / commenting it out fixes the problem. I didn't know that the `OnModelCreating` would affect what code EF generated!